# Need google query to only show sum of items greater than value from cell and another query to sum values based on selection

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 queries which need to be answered:

A)

```
=QUERY(Data!B:T,"select F, sum(I), sum(T) where D is not null AND E contains '"&Q2&"' AND G contains '"&S2&"' AND B contains '"&Q4&"' group by F order by sum(I) desc label sum(I) 'الكمية', sum(T) 'القيمة'",1)
```

I would like to add the condition to only show values greater than what is entered in cell 'S3'. I tried adding **AND sum(I) >= "&S3&"** but it showed an error. I tried with shifting quotes but nothing. How do I achieve this? Maybe with another query?

B)

```
=QUERY(Data!B:I,"select E, sum(I) where D is not null AND B contains '"&G4&"' AND C >= date '"&TEXT(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND C <= date '"&TEXT(I2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' group by E pivot G order by E",1)
```

I have a drop down list in cell 'I3' with 2 options, 'الكمية' and 'القيمة' and I would like the query to give me sum of values in 'I' in case of 'الكمية' and 'N' in case of 'القيمة'. How do I achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe post a slightly modified version of the question, with the arabic characters replaced by English. A link to a test sheet with a minimal problem will also help to get attention.

Comment: I'll try to answer both the question in one reply. Firstly, lets use the English term 'quantity' for 'الكمية' and 'value' for 'القيمة' to clear things a bit. 'Quantity' falls under column 'I' and 'value' under 'N.'

Now to answer @JPV's question, your solution will only give me quantities greater than that is 'S3' without summing up column 'I' whereas I'm looking for accumulated quantity and not individually sold.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=QUERY(Data!B:T,"select F, sum(I), sum(T) where D is not null AND I >= "&S3&" AND E contains '"&Q2&"' AND G contains '"&S2&"' AND B contains '"&Q4&"' group by F order by sum(I) desc label sum(I) 'الكمية', sum(T) 'القيمة'",1)
```

Comment: Hey! Your solution worked like a charm! Thanks a million!!!

Please help me solve the other query as well.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but I did not test your solution before posting the comment. There seems to be an error. It only filters the rows which consist of values greater than what I enter in 'S3' whereas I need it to filter the summed up quantity. Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tHg9ictxAKNj6uXiK3zlP-qT6krA8fV1pVDgAHq1W20/edit?pli=1#gid=1167817812&range=Q7) to the sheet. Please copy the data and see if you can get a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: @HuzaifaEzzi: Ok. so you want the summed values in I to be >= than S3? Can"t access your spreadsheet, please fix permissions.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Please find the query in cell 'Q7' of from the **Farmers' Interactive Summary** sheet of this [file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tHg9ictxAKNj6uXiK3zlP-qT6krA8fV1pVDgAHq1W20/edit?pli=1#gid=1167817812) . Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest do the sum of column I in one query, then wrap another query around it, filtering out the summed rows that do not meet the condition. Something like =QUERY(QUERY(Data!B:T,"select F, sum(I), sum(T) where D is not null  AND E contains '"&Q2&"' AND G contains '"&S2&"' AND B contains '"&Q4&"' group by F order by sum(I) desc label sum(I) 'الكمية', sum(T) 'القيمة'",1), "where Col2I >= "&T3&"")

Comment: Hey! I tried your solution and it gave me an error. There seems to be an error in the end where you have typed (I guessing accidentally) Col2I. It should be either Col2 or I. Can't be both. Anyway, I tried both but it didn't solve my problem. I'd appreciate it if you would test your queries before posting them. Thank for all your help though.